# why my computer do not showing hard drive in boot order

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

The computer does not start windows and it gives me a message: Your pc/device needs to be repaired.
The bios recognizes both the hdd and the new ssd (on which the OS is installed) in the device configuration, but in the boot order it does not show either of these two disks. It is the HP COMPAQ 6000 PRO motherboard. How to fix it?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this UEFI or BIOS? And which Windows version it came originally with? If Windows 8,x then the firmware (UEFI) and its default settings are already fine for Windows 10 in UEFI mode (as it should be). If Windows 7 then likely it has UEFI but with Legacy/CSM enabled and the OS installed in Legacy mode (settings should be changed to properly install Windows 10 fresh), If older then it has BIOS and we'll have an harder time troubleshooting.